# spark-sql through shell script | Amazon EMR

Tags: bash, shell, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I am super new to the command line environment and need some help. I am using spark-sql in my command line and I want to write a script to backup tables in glue.

**Need help writing a script to do the following**

1. `show create table test` (say, it produces the DDL below).
2. edit the first line of the output to `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_bkp` and the `Location` to `s3://stock-data /yahoo_finance/august_bkp`
3. run the edited DDL to create metadata for a backup table.

fyi, I am trying to run this in my EMR cluster. I enter into spark sql mode by typing spark-sql in the shell and then use sql commands to query athena.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (
  ID string,
  Ticker string,
  Starting double,
  CLosing double
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.paraquet.serde.ParaquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
‘path’='s3://stock-data /yahoo_finance/august’) 
LOCATION 
's3://stock-data /yahoo_finance/august'
PARTITIONED BY (timestamp string)
TBLPROPERTIES (
'spark.sql.partionProvider'='catalog'
'spark.sql.sourcesProvider'='paraquet')
```

I have gone through various videos, blogposts and articles and still have not found what I am looking for. I understand these questions are unusual here, but I will be forever indebted if someone could help.

Comment: If you are just looking to backup objects, I would recommend just using S3 replication and/or enable bucket versioning. If you still wanted to manually copy, using the `aws s3 sync` command would be significantly easier than trying to do this in EMR. It's also not clear what you are still missing as your don't mention any problems or errors with your existing solution.

Comment: I want to write a bash script to do what I have  described in the 3 steps above.

Comment: sync won't work (sorry about that, I have updated the question). I am trying to backup tables in glue (table data is stored in S3). I first create a copy of the S3 object that the data is in and then run sql commands in athena to create metadata for my table. I want to automate it with a bash script.